# Same entity class for table and view

Tags: nhibernate

I need to create view in nhibernate so in database i have table: SomeTable, and view SomeTableView. SomeTableView have same columns as SomeTable. Can I map somehow view so I could use same entity class with table and view?

Comment: If the table has the same columns as the view then why do you need to map the view? This doesn't quite make sense, unless you are not telling us the whole picture.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could create a new entity that inherits from `SomeTable` and create a new mapping for this new entity that uses the view instead.  This at least saves you from recreating all the same properties.