# View using same type as Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, view

I have a table that used throughout an app by Entity. I have a view that returns an identical column set, but is actually a union on itself to try to work around some bad normalization (The app is large and partially out of my hands, this part is unavoidable).

Is it possible to have Entity 4 treat a view that is exactly like a table as the same type, so that I can use this view to populate a collection of the same type? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064133/same-entity-class-for-table-and-view) seems to indicate it is possible in nhibernatem but I can't find anything like it for entity. It would be an extra bonus of the navigation properties could still be used to Include(), but this is not necessary (I can always manually join).

Comment: This is not possible right now. You should map to another type and do internal copying - e.g. with Automapper - for saving changes. I think the NHibernate link tells about the same, by the way. It would be a nice idea though, to have one type with different read and save paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since EF works on mappings from objects to database entities this is not directly possible. What you need is something like changing the queried database entity dynamically, and AFAIK this is not possible without manually changing the object context.

Answer (score 0):

For sure the EF runtime won't care as long as it can treat the view as if it was completely separate table. The two possible challenges that I forsee are:

1. Tooling: Our wizard does allow you to select views when doing reverse engineering (i.e. database-first). Definitively if you can use 'code first against an existing database' you can just pretend that the view is just a table, but you won't get any help scripting the database creation or migrations.
2. Updates: in general you can perform updates for a view setting up store procedure mapping (which is available in the EF Designer from v1 or in Code First starting in EF6). You might also be able to make your view updatable directly or using instead off triggers (see "Updatable Views" [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) for more details). If I remember correctly the SQL generated by EF to retrieve database generated values (e.g. for identity columns) is not compatible in some cases with instead-off triggers. Yet another alternative is to have your application treat the view as read-only and perform all updates through the actual table, which you would map as a separate entity. Keep in in mind that in-memory entities for the view and the original table will not be kept in sync.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I understand that my answer is a bit incomplete as I don't remember all the details of things that could go wrong, but I am planning to follow up on those. Just trying to provide some useful information as quickly as possible.

Comment: Updated with additional information. I originally missed mentioning that you can updates with stored procedures against a view.